# Overriding a Method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have recently started using [JsFormValidatorBundle](https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle) to validate my forms on symfony. The only issue is that i need to send these forms with Ajax and unfortunately for some reason the JsFormValidatorBundle forces the form to be sent by reloading the page.

So now i am trying to override that function which looks like:

```
    function FpJsCustomizeMethods() {

    ...

    this.submitForm = function (event) {
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            var element = item.jsFormValidator;
            if (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            element.validateRecursively();
            if (FpJsFormValidator.ajax.queue) {
                if (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                FpJsFormValidator.ajax.callbacks.push(function () {
                    element.onValidate.apply(element.domNode, [FpJsFormValidator.getAllErrors(element, {}), event]);
                    if (element.isValid()) {
                        item.submit();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                element.onValidate.apply(element.domNode, [FpJsFormValidator.getAllErrors(element, {}), event]);
                if (element.isValid()) {
                    item.submit();
                }
            }
        });
    };

....
}
```

if i remove the `item.submit()` it works perfectly.

So how can  override this?

**[full script](https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/public/js/fp_js_validator.js#L260)**

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a new function and extend the parent via its prototype.

Perhaps this code block can explain what you need to do.

```
function Parent() {

    this.a = function() {
        alert("i am here");
    }

    this.submitForm = function() {
        alert("i am wrong one here");
    }

}

function Child () {

    //we need to override function submitForm with right one
    this.submitForm = function() {
        alert("i am right one here");
    }

} 

Child.prototype = new Parent;

var c = new Child();
//other parent methods are still accessible.
c.a();
//method submitForm is overriden with the one we defined
c.submitForm();
```

see it in action [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/unx4rfd1/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i understand how it would work, but i just can not seem to get it to work with this particular JsFormValidatorBundle, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested you actually don't want to overwrite the `FpJsFormValidator.customizeMethods.submitForm` function just to be able to submit your forms via Ajax instead of default. Doing so will result in:

1. code duplication as you would be forced to restore all of the validation parts in your own function
2. and if part of your solution would be getting rid of the `item.submit()` bits then you would also lose any other events bound to be driggered by that submit as a by product.

I would instead simply create a handler for the submit event on that item which would call `event.preventDefault()` and do the Ajax request. As you tagged your question with jQuery, something like:

```
$("#your_fav_form_selector").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // fetch form data and send it off with $.ajax etc
});
```

Comment: Hi this is what i tried originally, and it actually fails, it seems the validation submit gets priority...

Comment: does any other submit handlers stop the submit event from bubbling (where you perform your ajax?)? all that the FpJsFormValidator.customizeMethods.submitForm seems to be doing is call the default submit event on that item and if the bubbling is intact it shouldn't matter which one of them gets the priority

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways of doing that.
As far as I know, the function you want to override isn't a jQuery function. I kept the 2 examples so that you can decide which one fits in your code.

**If it's a JavaScript function (custom or native)**

First of all, I saw the function you're using and I find that it's hard to override a specific part of it, so I wrote it again and removed (or commented out) the "submit call" and then I've overridden the function. When calling `FpJsFormValidator`, the following function will be called `NewFpJsCustomizeMethods`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FpJsFormValidator = function() {
    return NewFpJsCustomizeMethods();
}

function NewFpJsCustomizeMethods() {
    this.init = function (options) {
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            if (!item.jsFormValidator) {
                item.jsFormValidator = {};
            }
            for (var optName in options) {
                switch (optName) {
                    case 'customEvents':
                        options[optName].apply(item);
                    break;
                    default:
                        item.jsFormValidator[optName] = options[optName];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, false);
        return this;
    };
    this.validate = function (opts) {
        var isValid = true;
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            var method = (opts && true === opts['recursive'])
                ? 'validateRecursively'
                : 'validate';
            var validateUnique = (!opts || false !== opts['findUniqueConstraint']);
            if (validateUnique && item.jsFormValidator.parent) {
                var data = item.jsFormValidator.parent.data;
                if (data['entity'] && data['entity']['constraints']) {
                    for (var i in data['entity']['constraints']) {
                        var constraint = data['entity']['constraints'][i];
                        if (constraint instanceof FpJsFormValidatorBundleFormConstraintUniqueEntity && constraint.fields.indexOf(item.name)) {
                            var owner = item.jsFormValidator.parent;
                            constraint.validate(null, owner);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!item.jsFormValidator[method]()) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });
        return isValid;
    };
    this.showErrors = function (opts) {
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            item.jsFormValidator.errors[opts['sourceId']] = opts['errors'];
            item.jsFormValidator.showErrors.apply(item, [opts['errors'], opts['sourceId']]);
        });
    };
    this.submitForm = function (event) {
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            var element = item.jsFormValidator;
            if (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            element.validateRecursively();
            if (FpJsFormValidator.ajax.queue) {
                if (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                FpJsFormValidator.ajax.callbacks.push(function () {
                    element.onValidate.apply(element.domNode, [FpJsFormValidator.getAllErrors(element, {}), event]);
                    if (element.isValid()) {
                        //item.submit();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                element.onValidate.apply(element.domNode, [FpJsFormValidator.getAllErrors(element, {}), event]);
                if (element.isValid()) {
                    //item.submit();
                }
            }
        });
    };
    this.get = function () {
        var elements = [];
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            elements.push(item.jsFormValidator);
        });
        return elements;
    };
    //noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
    this.addPrototype = function(name) {
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            var prototype = FpJsFormValidator.preparePrototype(
            FpJsFormValidator.cloneObject(item.jsFormValidator.prototype),
                name,
                item.jsFormValidator.id + '_' + name
            );
            item.jsFormValidator.children[name] = FpJsFormValidator.createElement(prototype);
            item.jsFormValidator.children[name].parent = item.jsFormValidator;
        });
    };
    //noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
    this.delPrototype = function(name) {
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            delete (item.jsFormValidator.children[name]);
        });
    };
}
</script>
```

**If it's a jQuery function**

First of all, I saw the function you're using and I find that it's hard to override a specific part of it, so I wrote it again and removed (or commented out) the "submit call" and then I've overridden the jQuery function. When calling `FpJsFormValidator`, the following function will be called `NewFpJsCustomizeMethods`.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    // Define overriding method
    jQuery.fn.FpJsFormValidator = NewFpJsCustomizeMethods();
})();

function NewFpJsCustomizeMethods() {
    this.init = function (options) {
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            if (!item.jsFormValidator) {
                item.jsFormValidator = {};
            }
            for (var optName in options) {
                switch (optName) {
                    case 'customEvents':
                        options[optName].apply(item);
                    break;
                    default:
                        item.jsFormValidator[optName] = options[optName];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, false);
        return this;
    };
    this.validate = function (opts) {
        var isValid = true;
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            var method = (opts && true === opts['recursive'])
                ? 'validateRecursively'
                : 'validate';
            var validateUnique = (!opts || false !== opts['findUniqueConstraint']);
            if (validateUnique && item.jsFormValidator.parent) {
                var data = item.jsFormValidator.parent.data;
                if (data['entity'] && data['entity']['constraints']) {
                    for (var i in data['entity']['constraints']) {
                        var constraint = data['entity']['constraints'][i];
                        if (constraint instanceof FpJsFormValidatorBundleFormConstraintUniqueEntity && constraint.fields.indexOf(item.name)) {
                            var owner = item.jsFormValidator.parent;
                            constraint.validate(null, owner);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!item.jsFormValidator[method]()) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });
        return isValid;
    };
    this.showErrors = function (opts) {
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            item.jsFormValidator.errors[opts['sourceId']] = opts['errors'];
            item.jsFormValidator.showErrors.apply(item, [opts['errors'], opts['sourceId']]);
        });
    };
    this.submitForm = function (event) {
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            var element = item.jsFormValidator;
            if (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            element.validateRecursively();
            if (FpJsFormValidator.ajax.queue) {
                if (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                FpJsFormValidator.ajax.callbacks.push(function () {
                    element.onValidate.apply(element.domNode, [FpJsFormValidator.getAllErrors(element, {}), event]);
                    if (element.isValid()) {
                        //item.submit();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                element.onValidate.apply(element.domNode, [FpJsFormValidator.getAllErrors(element, {}), event]);
                if (element.isValid()) {
                    //item.submit();
                }
            }
        });
    };
    this.get = function () {
        var elements = [];
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            elements.push(item.jsFormValidator);
        });
        return elements;
    };
    //noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
    this.addPrototype = function(name) {
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            var prototype = FpJsFormValidator.preparePrototype(
            FpJsFormValidator.cloneObject(item.jsFormValidator.prototype),
                name,
                item.jsFormValidator.id + '_' + name
            );
            item.jsFormValidator.children[name] = FpJsFormValidator.createElement(prototype);
            item.jsFormValidator.children[name].parent = item.jsFormValidator;
        });
    };
    //noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
    this.delPrototype = function(name) {
        //noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
        FpJsFormValidator.each(this, function (item) {
            delete (item.jsFormValidator.children[name]);
        });
    };
}
</script>
```

Second of all, if you're looking to override some stuff in the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    // Store a reference to the original method.
    var originalMethod = jQuery.fn.FpJsFormValidator;

    // Define overriding method.
    jQuery.fn.FpJsFormValidator = function(){
        // Execute the original method.
        originalMethod.apply( this, arguments );
    }
})();
</script>
```

**Note:**

You need to write this code after loading the original function.

Comment: That seems like an awful lot of repetition, please see my answer, which did actually work.

Comment: It's exactly what I wrote, but I didn't have time to go through every line in the library you provided, so I just explained the concept of overriding a function in JavaScript and also in a jQuery object.